# Override the compiler prefix generated by autotools

Tags: gcc, cross-platform, cross-compiling, autotools

I have a suite of small programs and libraries that run on several embedded systems running different platforms that our company uses. One of the platforms uses a gcc 2.95.3 compiler with gcc being `ppc_405-gcc`, which obviously doesn't match the conventional modern naming scheme for gcc cross compilers (e.g. i686-pc-linux-gnu). I want to use autotools to create a new program to target these PowerPC boards running an old version of BusyBox linux running a 2.4 series kernel. The flags I use are : `--build=i686-pc-linux-gnu --host=powerpc-none-linux  --target=powerpc-none-linux` and when Autotools runs it searches for `powerpc-none-linux-g++` et al. Is there any way to override the tool prefix so that it searches for `ppc_405-gcc` et al ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just tell it:

```
./configure CC=ppc_405-gcc CXX=ppc_405-g++ LD=ppc_405-ld STRIP=ppc_405-strip ...
```

Comment: This is what I wound up going with as I couldn't find any setting in autotools that would set the prefix for all programs in the gcc suite.

Comment: @AlexMarshall `--host` is what sets an internal variable in `configure` to the prefix.  In this case `--host` is non-standard and might break other stuff relying on those variables (`$host_cpu`, `$host_os`) which could in turn could break `configure`.